# NumberFormat.format is also formatting digits as per locale

Tags: java, nsnumberformatter

NumberFormat.format is changing 1000Rs to ₹ ১,০০০.০০ which are actually digits in Bangla language, similar thing is happening for IQD there it is getting changed in Iraqi language digit. How can we format by keeping digits in 1-9 only and get only formatting for separator and decimal point as per locale

```
NumberFormat amountFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(
                Locale.getdefault());
String formattedAmount = amountFormatter.format(Double.parseDouble(actualAmount))
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] ?

Comment: added sample code

Comment: As Locale.getDefault() is different on various systems, could you please give us the result of `Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag()` as String? Or update the example with `Locale.forLanguageTag("...")` with the correct language tag to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Instead of Locale.getDefault(), try `new Locale("en", "IN")`.  Also:  **Never** use double to represent currency, as it can actually lose some of the numbers.  Use `new BigDecimal(actualAmount)` instead of Double.parseDouble.

Comment: got solution by setting DecimalFormatSymbols.setZeroDigit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. We can get DecimalFormatSymbols instance and set Zerodigit character to avoid other digits symbol

```
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((DecimalFormat) numberFormat).getDecimalFormatSymbols();
            decimalFormatSymbols.setZeroDigit('0');
```